# If $u$ is harmonic in $B(0,1)\subset\mathbb R^2$ with $\vert u\vert\leq1,$ then $\vert\nabla u(0)\vert\leq4/\pi$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

Let $u$ be harmonic in $B(0,1)\subset\mathbb R^2$ and $\vert u\vert\leq1,$ then $\vert\nabla u(0,0)\vert\leq4/\pi.$

Since $\vert\nabla u(0,0)\vert=\sqrt{u_{x}(0,0)^2+u_{y}(0,0)^2}$, we need to estimate the previous two partial derivatives at the origin. Using the mean value formula for harmonic functions we find that
$$\vert u_x(0,0)\vert=\left\vert\frac{1}{\vert B(0,\pi/4)\vert}\int_{B(0,\pi/4)}u_x(x,y)\,dx\,dy\right\vert=\frac{2^2}{\alpha(2)(\pi/2)^2}\left\vert\int_{\partial B(0,\pi/4)}u\nu_x\,dS\right\vert\leq\frac{4\cdot2\cdot2}{\pi},$$
however, this does not yield the bound we are after, and I see no way to improve on the calculation above.
Does anyone have any suggestions on how to improve this bound?

Comment: Is $u(0) = 0$ also given? In that case you can apply https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3581789/42969.

Comment: @MartinR Nope, it is not given. Thank you for your feedback. Upon more research, I found this post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3176402/bound-on-gradient-of-harmonic-functions. Here Matematleta uses a form of Harnack's inequality that can be proved using the Poisson formula for harmonic functions in $\mathbb R^2$. I think that this should work. I could rephrase it into a real analysis setting and done. What do you think?

Comment: That other solutions gives you only $\vert\nabla u(0,0)\vert\leq 2$, doesn't it?

Comment: @MartinR You are right, we would need to set $R=\pi/2$ at the end of the proof, but that is not allowed because we must have $B(0,R)\subseteq B(0,1).$

Answer (score 1):

One can proceed similar as in [Estimate $|f’(0)|$ by $Re(f(z))$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3581789/estimate-f-0-by-refz).

If we identify $\Bbb R^2$ with $\Bbb C$ then $u$ is the real part of a holomorphic function $f$ in the complex unit disk $\Bbb D$. The goal is to show that $|\nabla u(0)| = |f'(0)| \le 4/\pi$.

We can assume that the strict inequality $|\operatorname{Re}(z)| < 1$ holds in $\Bbb D$ because $f$ is constant otherwise. Then
$$
g(z) = \tan\left(\frac \pi 4 f(z)\right)
$$
maps the unit disk into itself, so that the [Schwarz–Pick theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma#Schwarz%E2%80%93Pick_theorem) can be applied to $g$ at $z=0$:
$$
 1 - |g(0)|^2 \ge |g'(0)| = \left| \frac{\frac \pi 4 f'(0)}{1 + \tan^2\left(\frac \pi 4 f(0)\right)} \right| = \frac \pi 4 |f'(0)| \, .
$$
i.e. $ |f'(0)| \le \frac 4 \pi (1 - |g(0)|^2) \le \frac 4 \pi$.